# Find compound growth rate from cumulative totals

Tags: finance, percentages

I'm a bit out of my depth here, so please feel free to correct any errors in terminology, etc.

I'm looking to solve for a percentage growth rate. I know the starting population, the number of compounding periods, and the **cumulative** total of the population.

When I say **cumulative**, I mean the sum total of each compounding period. An example:

- Starting population: `100`
- Compounding periods: `3`
- Cumulative total: `331`

In this case, the growth rate turns out to be `10%`, because:

- Period 1: `100`
- Period 2: `110`
- Period 3: `121`
- Cumulative Total: `100 + 110 + 121 = 331`

What I'm looking for is an equation that describes this relationship, like:

`Percent growth = ...`

Any ideas?

Comment: The question isn't really clear, are you talking about the total percent growth? or percent growth per compounding period?

Comment: @DR01D sorry for the lack of clarity. I'm interested in the percent growth per compounding period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cummulative total is $S_n=100+110+121$. It can be transformed by factoring out 1.1 and $1.1^2$.

$S_n=100+1.1\cdot 100+1.1^2\cdot 100$ This is the partial sum of a geometric series.

The formula for the partial sum of a geometric series is $S_n=C_0\cdot \frac{(1+g)^n-1}{g}$

$C_0$ is the starting population. $g$ is the growth rate. In your example $C_0=100,n=3$ and $S_n=100$

The formula can be transformed. $S_n\cdot g=C_0\cdot (1+g)^n-C_0$ This equation has to be solved for g.

If n=2, then you have a quadratic equation. It easy to solve.

In your case it is n=3: Here you can apply [Cardano´s method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) or use an approximation method like the [Newton–Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Both methods are time-consuming.